# While running first time Dsl script working, but after updated dsl script facing the problem

Tags: jenkins, dsl

I written simple DSL script for Jenkins job creation. first day I created Jenkins job by using my DSL script. After that am unable to create the another Jenkins job by using same script. while running my DSL script build is SUCCESS and it showing the GENERATED ITEM name(i.e job name and path), but am unable to find the created new job in particular PATH And unable to find the SEED job name in DSL job.

My DSL Script look like

```
def ciBuild = "job/dsl_script_job"

job(ciBuild) {

      scm {
         git('git://github.com/oveits/java-maven-junit-helloworld')
      }
      triggers {
         scm('H/15 * * * *')
      }
      steps {
         maven('-e clean test')
      }
}
```

Note: "job" ---> folder name

```
   "dsl_script_job" -------> Job Name.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create two jobs via DSL, then you need to call `job()` twice. Like this:

```
job("job/dsl_script_job")   { [...] }
job("job/dsl_script_job_2") { [...] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Above problem is DSL plugin issue. so upgrade the DSL plugin to updated version

Recommended DSL plugin version is 1.60+